# Cassandra: Insert multiple rows containing different data with the same set of primary key values

Tags: node.js, insert, cassandra, time-series, cql

Say I have 2 rows of time-series data that have exactly the same timestamp etc for the primary keys. The only difference is the rest of the data are different.
So if set 1 has [timestamp, other keys...], value_col1, value_col2, then the value_col1 and value_col2 for set 2 will have different values than set 1.

Now if I put those sets into one batch to be inserted or very quickly using seperate inserts queries, the result I see in the database can be somewhat inconsistent: it can be that value_col1 from set 1 is combined with that of value_col2 in the final row.

It took me the whole evening to find out this is actually a bug (or maybe intended behaviour...) I have my workaround now using a slightly increased timestamp for set 2. The sympton won't be noticed in many cases, but in my case where col1 is the partial decoding key for col2, then I have a problem!
Does anyone have the same problem or knows where the problem actually lies?

I'm using cassandra-node drive on nodejs 5.0.0 with cassandra 2.0.14.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your in Cassandra schema to avoid race conditions.

If you provide different data with same partition and clustering keys in the same instant, you will not be able to define which should be preserved.

If you want the 2 rows to be preserved, you should use a `uuid` or `timeuuid` datatypes.

See more information in the nodejs driver docs: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/2.2/nodejs-driver/reference/uuids-timeuuids.html

Comment: Hi Jorgebg, to me, it really doesn't matter which of the two sets get inserted. Imho, cassandra/node-driver doesn't deal with it correcly by randomly select columns from 2 sets of data, it should either select the entire first set or the entire second set. I know this may not sound like a big deal to most users, but when encryption is involved, I just can't have this mess up my data. Anyway, a workaround is easy to implement.